# Why does this bash script not work?

Tags: bash

When I run the following command

```
./command *
```

using this script

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in ./$1
do
    echo $f
done
```

only the first file specified in $1 is echoed. My question is why?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to resize images using the following syntax: scale 1024x768 *.jpg. When passing *.jpg as a parameter my script only processes the first file found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't used simple or double quotes when you ran your command:

```bsh
./command '*'
```

or:

```bsh
./command "*"
```

Or, if you want certainly to use `./command *`, then make the following modification in your script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for f in ./"$@"
do
    echo $f
done
```

That's because `$1` refers to the first argument from your command ans `$@` refers to all arguments from your command.

Read also some documentation in this sense: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF

Answer (score 2):

The shell expands the `*` when you run the command. So, running the script is equivalent to

```
./command file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

`$1` corresponds to the first argument, therefore the loop only has one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

`$1` only refers to the first argument. You need to use `$*`.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in $*
do
     echo $f
done
```

Comment: No, never use `$*` unless you know _exactly_ what it means. Use `"$@"` (with quotes) instead.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Your comment is not helpful because it does not provide substantial information.

Comment: My comments are never helpful. Oh, unless you're willing to learn the difference between `$*` and `$@`, in which case you can have a look at the references online. It's free, I've been told. For example [this reference about Bash's special parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Sorry, I already read this, but still do not understand the problem. I am willing to learn, but if your are not willing to explain, maybe your not at the right place.

Comment: `$*` is broken if you give parameters containing spaces. `"$*"` expands to just one word, so it's not good. The only possibility is `"$@"` (quoted) that will work regardless how funny the symbols are in the arguments.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Thx.